# Are sprouting wheat berries safe?

Tags: food-safety, boiling, wheat, sprouting

I soaked some wheat berries for a bit more than 24 hours and now some white stuff comes out of it.

Is it safe if I boil and eat it as I usually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [healthline.com](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/sprouted-grain-bread):

> In one study, sprouting wheat increased the absorption of iron by over 200% ( 16 ). Sprouted grains are higher in several nutrients, including protein, fiber, vitamin C, folate and beta-carotene. In addition, sprouting decreases antinutrients, making the nutrients in the grains more readily available to your body.

From 
[Cultures For Health](https://www.culturesforhealth.com/learn/sprouting/how-to-sprout-wheat-berries/):

> How to Use Sprouted Wheat Berries. Add to salads, soups, bread, and other recipes. Ferment sprouted wheat berries to make Rejuvelac. Transfer to soil and grow wheat grass for making wheat grass juice.

From 
[Kitchn](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-sprouted-grains-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-204466):

> **Sprouted grains, like wheat berries** and rice, are super simple, don’t require any major equipment, and are fun for both adults and kids to make. To make them actually sprout, the soaked grains are then rinsed, drained, and kept moist inside a jar for a period of 1 to 5 days. Sprouted grains **are often eaten raw, lightly cooked, or ground into flour**.

Seems like sprouted wheat berries are a common edible food.

Comment: Thanks, that’s the bit that makes it a good answer. (In fact, the last quote alone would be sufficient.)